# Implement a -verbose output from within a ForEach loop in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, 7zip, verbose

I am writing a script to archive some log files older than 6 months to a 7zip file then delete the original files. I want to implement a -verbose output so that a log file is created listing what files were archived and deleted successfully. The output of deleted files is reporting correctly, however I don't know where in the code to implement the -verbose for confirming the archiving to a 7z file.

```
# start logging of archived files and specify log location for each day 
Start-transcript C:\Temp\LogArchiveTesting\Logs\Archived_Server_Logging_$(get-date -format ddMMMyyyy).log


# set folder path
$log_path = "C:\Temp\LogArchiveTesting\*.*"
$zip_path = "C:\Temp\LogArchiveTesting\Archive\*.7z"
$target_path = "C:\Temp\LogArchiveTesting\Archive\"

# set min age of files
$max_months = "-6"
$delete_max_days = "-365"

# get the current date
$curr_date = Get-Date

# determine how far back we go based on current date
$zip_date = $curr_date.AddMonths($max_months)
$delete_zip_date = $curr_date.AddDays($delete_max_days)

#$zip_date = (Get-Date).AddMonths(0).Month

# filter files
Get-ChildItem $log_path | Where-Object { ($_.LastWriteTime -lt $zip_date) -and ($_.psIsContainer -eq $false)}|

  ForEach {
    $Zip = $target_path + "{0:yyMM}_{0:MMM}Server Logging.7z" -f $_.LastWriteTime
    & "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" u -mx9 -t7z -m0=lzma2  $Zip $_.FullName |Out-Null
    If ($LastExitCode -eq 0) { Remove-Item $_.FullName }
  }

$deletefile = Get-ChildItem $zip_path | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $delete_zip_date } | Remove-Item -verbose

#Stops logging of archived files
stop-transcript
```

Comment: Do you want to write something to a logfile when the operation ran succesfully? Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: @rpm192 original post updated

Comment: I suggest using the [tag:7zip] [tag:.net] library.  Without unpacking the archive for every file, I don't think the executable has that capability to check an archive for a file.

Comment: [See their SDK download link](https://www.7-zip.org/download.html)